# in cshell: How to I set a variable to the command line output?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, jobs, csh, job-scheduling

I do want to start a batch job that generates a jobid as output.
How can I save the jobid as environmental variable and reuse it in the cshell script?
Thanks and best wishes,
Rollz

Answer (score 2):

Use backticks to substitute the output of a command into the command line. To set an ordinary variable:

```
set varname = `start_batch_job`
```

To set an environment variable:

```
setenv varname `start_batch_job`
```

You should generally avoid scripting in C-shell, it has lots of problems that make it poor as a scripting language. See [Csh Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). Even if you use it as your interactive shell, you can still use another shell, such as bash or ksh, as a scripting language (except for your shell startup scripts, of course).

Comment: I understand why whenever people give an answer to a csh question they always say not to use csh, but sometimes there is literally no other option because of the business environment people are in.