# How to get WHICH WHOAMI result into variable in CSH

Tags: csh

I want to put WHICH WHOAMI result into variable in c shell. I know I can make it like this in bash:

```
x=$(which whoami)
echo $x
```

But I have no idea how to achieve this in c shell.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered [previously here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18001113/in-cshell-how-to-i-set-a-variable-to-the-command-line-output) you may use the backtick in combination with set or setenv. As such:

```
set x = `which whoami`    # Ordinary variable
setenv x = `which whoami` # Environment variable
```

Please use the search box in the top right corner of this very page next time, with a simple query like: "csh command output in variable" before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

one other option in TCSH would be to output your results to a file and then reference the file:

> #! /usr/bin/tcsh -f
>
> touch text_files.list
>
> find . -name "*.txt" > text_files.list

This should output the find results to a file which you can then reference